# Is SonarQube sufficient for static code reviews?

Tags: sonarqube, static-analysis, checkstyle, pmd, spotbugs

My applications are based on [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language)) and [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)).
Besides [SonarQube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SonarQube) there are other popular tools like:

**Amazon CodeGuru** helps you improve code quality and automate code reviews by scanning and profiling Java and Python applications. CodeGuru Reviewer can detect potential defects and bugs in your code.

**Synopsys Coverity Static Analysis** identifies critical software quality defects and security vulnerabilities in code and any lapses in industry compliance standards.

**PMD** is most useful when integrated into your build process. It can then be used as a quality gate, to enforce a coding standard for your codebase

**Checkstyle** is a development tool to help programmers write Java code that adheres to a coding standard. It automates the process of checking Java code to spare humans of this boring (but important) task.

**SpotBugs** is a program which uses static analysis to look for bugs in Java code.

Considering the power all these tools resides in SonarQube. Should I use only SonarQube or combination of these are required?

I study various [static code analysers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) and am looking for a recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All static analyzers are different based on their own communities. Some analyzers have different checks or logic that none of the others have. Even if 2 analyzers have the same check, one could work better than the other, or one may be easier to run locally before submitting to a CI for a more in-depth review.

I recommend to enabling as many different analyzers as you can as long as they let you turn checks on/off and disable violations that you disagree with. Customizing these tools to the style of your project is what ultimately matters.